# how to remove special characters and number patterns from a string in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a string
`"<U+7F85><U+934F><U+6DC7> <U+2730> Sascha Banks"`

I want to exclude everything except the name `"Sacha Banks"`.

I perform:

```
name1<-c("<U+7F85><U+934F><U+6DC7> <U+2730> Sascha Banks ")
name2<-str_replace_all(name1, "[^[:alnum:]]", " ")
```

Actual Output: `" U 7F85  U 934F  U 6DC7   U 2730  Sascha Banks "`

Expected Output: `" Sascha Banks "`

Please correct me.

Comment: Do you want to keep whitespace also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
x <- "<U+7F85><U+934F><U+6DC7> <U+2730> Sascha Banks"
gsub("(<.*>)", "", x)
## [1] " Sascha Banks"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
gsub("<[^>]*>", "", name1)
## [1] "  Sascha Banks "
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care to learn the regex this is a pretty straight forward approach that removes all angle brackets:

```
library(qdap)
bracketX("<U+7F85><U+934F><U+6DC7> <U+2730> Sascha Banks", "angle")

## [1] "Sascha Banks"
```